# PYTHON LOGIN SYSTEM

Tags: python

```
def loginadmin():
    checker = -1
    print (" \n******* ADMIN Login *******\n")
    id = input("ID: ")
    pw = input("Password: ")
    with open ("adminid.txt", "r") as adminlogin:
        for rec in range (0,len(adminlogin)):
            if (userid == adminlogin[rec][0]) and (pw == adminlogin[rec][1]):
                checker = rec
                break
            else:
                return flg 
    adminlogin.close
    status = loginadmin()
    if (status != -1):
        print (" \n******* Login Successful *******\n")
        print ("Welcome Admin ", adminlogin[status][2])
    else:
        print (" \n******* user not found *******\n")
        loginadmin ()

loginadmin()
```

what did i do wrong? trying to create a login system for my assignment.
i need to find id in txt file and password too.
make sure the password belongs to the id

Comment: This line is redundant `adminlogin.close`

Comment: _what did i do wrong?_ If you're getting errors or unexpected results, show them to us, and explain what you wanted instead.

Comment: `adminlogin[rec][0]` would be only the first character, but you can't actually jump around file indexes like this.

Comment: You are calling your function from within your function.

Comment: Hard to count what you did right. There is no variable `flg` defined before you return it. You have an infinite recursion from calling loginadmin(), etc

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover Technically, it's just meaningless, since it's not *calling* the `close` method, only referencing it.

Comment: `adminlogin` is a file but you're accessing as though it were a list. It doesn't have a `len()`

Comment: Also post sample contents of the adminid.txt file.

Comment: Why does `loginadmin` call itself recursively multiple times?

Comment: @chepner `with` does what with a file when the `with` is finished executing?

Comment: Yes, but you need a *call* to `close` before you can say that that call is redundant.

Comment: If with issues a close on its own than having a close written in is not needed. its like writing `x=4` multiple times within a few lines without assigning a new value to x

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.